Flat SRID with wrapping on both axis ? (torus shape)
I am using PostGIS data to display a flat world. Until now, I've used the bare geometry system with no specific SRID.
I am trying to find a way to connect both axis ends together, east with west and north with south, making the world it represents the shape of a torus. The reference system I'm thinking about would be :

flat, no spheroid feature
the coordinates would have a minimum and a maximum
those ending coordinates would actually represent the same place (like the 180 and -180 longitude on earth) on both axis
computations like distances, intersections, containing would take into account this wrapping

Is there a known SRID looking like that? Is it even achievable?

Can you find anything that satisfies you from https://anderson.map-projections.net/?

It's hard to tell, they seem all made for a spherical world

Have a look at this: https://map-projections.net/singleview.php

It would be an hybrid between the Cassini where all edges connect together and the Equirectangular which preserves angles.

I've never heard of anything supported by a GIS or the PROJ library. (30 years supporting map projections)

It's not flat if it defines a torus.  Wouldn't you want some XYZ system that defines offsets from a circle

@nmtoken You're right, it's not exactly a torus in the projection aspect. More of an imaginary one where the "inner equator" has the same length as the "outer equator". For my use case, it works great to consider it a flat surface. The only thing I need from the torus definition is to connect the edges and to have distances (among other operations) computed accordingly : it would for instance be 0 between all corners of the projection and not the whole bounds or its diagonal.

would cylinder be a better description
